# Conversion table returning 0 values within loop

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

Prompt was to write a program using mips loop concepts and syntax that converts and displays Km to Mi conversion table for every whole number from 0-20 Km inclusively and their Mi equivalents in the console.
I wrote this in MARS(required)
the code below prints the would be conversion table for the 20 whole KMs, however for each element the values for both Km and Mi are left at 0.0 as displayed below
Output:

```
Km,Mi,
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
0.0km0.0mi
```

After further review 21 total lines are printed which I'm unsure why.

```
.data
milesstr: .asciiz "mi"
linestr: .asciiz "\n"
kilomstr: .asciiz "km"
conversion: .float 1.609344
header:  .asciiz "Km,Mi,\n"
.text
.globl main
main:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,header
    syscall
    li $s0,0
loop:
    bgt $s0,20,exit
    mtc1 $s0,$f4
    lwc1 $f6,conversion 
    mul.s $f4,$f4,$f6
    li $v0,2
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,kilomstr
    syscall
    li $v0,2
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,milesstr
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,linestr
    syscall
    addi $s0,$s0,1
    j loop
    exit:
    li $v0,10
    syscall
```

Judging by the output I believe the program is entering and exiting the loop fine, however the actual math logic is not being completed, as well as an extra element is printed unnecessarily. Any help would be great! I'm assuming it has to be an error in by conversion variable, but any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `mtc1` just copies the bits as-is. You need some form of conversion as well, e.g. `cvt.s.w $f4, $f4`

Comment: Also, system call 2 expects the value to print in register `$f12`.

Comment: Follow Michael's suggestions.  As far as the extra element, use the debugger: single step, make the program do something trivial (print one element) to make it easier to debug.

Comment: Mike your the man! helped me out perfectly thanks alot